# changing source from multiple dependencies - scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx

Say I have one unlocked packaged that has all my custom objects and fields, and another that is the page layouts for each object. So basically I have two dependencies before I can start a new dx project.

Then I start a new a dx project, and during development I add a few fields, maybe change one of the page layouts. I then do

`sfdx force:source:pull -u myScratchOrg`

Doing so, I've pulled source that should belong in my dependencies, but is now in my current project, correct? Was that the wrong development workflow? Do I need to update each dependency before I install them in my scratch org? Or is there a way to get the source I just pulled and divvy it up into the appropriate dependencies from within my current sfdx project?